# Chrome Extension: Content of localStorage is not visible in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

I have a problem seeing content of the local storage for **chrome-extension** in DevTools (it works for regular websites, only problem is for the **chrome-extension**). I have tried to check  **Resources > Local Storage** for regular page, but also for the popup and background inspection pages of my chrome-extension.

If i open console and execute:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('config', function(result) {console.log(JSON.stringify(result));});
```

I get

```
{"config":{"version":"0.4.1"}}
```

But not visible under **Resources > Local Storage**

I can also set

```
chrome.storage.local.set({"config":{"version":"0.5"}});
```

And re-read the new value: 0.5.

**NOTE**: In the Resources > Local Storage I do see the entry for my extension: chrome-extension:ld... , but i do not see any key/value there.

Any idea why this is happening, and how i can see values under under the **Resources > Local Storage**.

I am not aware of any way to enable access to it in **manifest.json**, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Any data stored in `chrome.storage.*` API will not appear in resources panel as these APIs are different from `localStorage` and not just a wrapper around it.

> This API has been optimized to meet the specific storage needs of
>   extensions. It provides the same storage capabilities as the
>   localStorage API with the following key differences:
>
> ...
>   ...
>
> It's asynchronous with bulk read and write operations, and
>   therefore faster than the blocking and serial localStorage API.
>
> User
>   data can be stored as objects (the localStorage API stores data in
>   strings).
>
> ...

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, but it IS the most likely based on the SAME storage with an additional wrapper for object serialization (and vice versa) and asynchronous support, which you can see from the same page you have referred:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage
'... JSON stringification of every value plus every key's length ... '.

And anyway, I am quite sure there must be a way to access the content in the Chrome DevTools.

Comment: Is there a solution to this in 2020? I want to view, edit and clear my local storage of chrome extension!!